# External script and unapplied migrations

Tags: python, django, subprocess, django-migrations

I am writing script supporting my Django project development. First I thought of using bash for this purpose but due to lack of enough knowledge and total lack of time I decided to write something using argparse and running system commands using subprocess.

Everything went ok until I had to run

```
./manage.py migrate
```

I do it by running:

```
import subprocess
...
subprocess.Popen("python {} migrate".format(absolute_path_to_manage_py).split())
```

The output seems to look ok:

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, auth, contenttypes, accounts, pcb
Running migrations:
Rendering model states... DONE
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
...
Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

And it stops suddenly, but script is still active (it's still running) and what's worse when I run django app I get a message that I still have some unapplied migrations.

I think I don't know something about running system commands from Python or something related to django migrations.

Any hint how I could overcome this?

Comment: POpen is unblocking function. You should pass PIPEs or use blocking function. You can try subprocess.check_call https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: try `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'manage.py', 'migrate'], cwd=os.path.dirname(absolute_path_to_manage_py))`, to run `manage.py` from its directory and to wait for it to finish (raising an exception on non-zero exit status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

> The recommended way to launch subprocesses is to use the following
>   convenience functions. For more advanced use cases when these do not
>   meet your needs, use the underlying `Popen` interface.

You could use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), which waits for the command to complete:

```
returncode = subprocess.call(["python", absolute_path_to_manage_py, "migrate"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a subprocess, you can call the management command directly using [`call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command):

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('migrate')
```